# Put html/view logic inside razor file or in the viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a table with an integer column.

Depending on the integer value I want to make the text in the cell red or green.

Something like this is what many people do:

List.cshtml:

```
string style = @DaysLeft <= 30 ? "background-color:Red" : "background-color:Green";
<td style="@style">
    ...
</td>
```

If I would put the logic in a viewmodel:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    BackgroundColorClass = DaysLeft > 100 ? "Background-color:red" : "Background-color:green";
}
```

and the class assignment in the view:

```
<td  class="CenterOrientedColumns teststateField">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DaysLeft, new{ @class = Model.BackgroundColorClass})
    </td>
```

Why does this logic belong not in the viewmodel?

Comment: Do you mean why does this logic not belong in the _view_?

Comment: @OllieP Yes where belongs this logic and why concerning that asp.net mvc is the Model View Controller pattern. The logic could be much more in the view and the unit testability decreases to zero...

Comment: I assume `Background-color:red` is style, not class... So you need to: `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DaysLeft, new{ @style = Model.BackgroundColorClass})`

Comment: @WeTTTT I know just a grammar. Its not about how to do the datatrigger, I ask about why put it where...

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to ask? First of all your "ViewModel" is not a class at all, it is just a method, and I have no idea where you initiated `BackgroundColorClass`. I don't believe the example code you provided will even compile.

Comment: My ViewModel shows the constructor of a class and the BackgroundColorClass is just an automatic property.